# How to get the image's type (RGB or GREY)

Tags: python, gimp

I'm trying to use the GIMP python plugin [Density Brush Fill](http://registry.gimp.org/node/25834). In one place, it assumes that it's being used on a color image and crashes when used with a greyscale one:

```
self.layer=gimp.Layer( self.image,[...], RGBA_IMAGE, 100, NORMAL_MODE)
```

The fix would be quite easy however I haven't found any API documentation for `image`. How to get the type (color or greyscale) of the image?

Comment: If you can print out or display the results of a `dir(self.image)` call, you may be able see what attributes image's have which may be provide a clue as to what to look at to determine the image type. Alternatively, since it's open-source, you can always read that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [**Image Object**](http://www.gimp.org/docs/python/index.html#image_object) section of the GIMP Python Documentation it mentions a `image.base_type` member that sounds like what you want.

Comment: Also, whenever in doubt about how to do something, one should check the "procedural database"  - they are equivalent tot he object methods and attributes, as they are what GIMP-Python uses underneath

Comment: Probably, I'll accept the answer once I get around to test it.

Answer (score 0):

What about getting number of channels? 1,2,3,4 = GRAY,GRAYA,RGB,RGBA

But I must admit I dont know if channels has names at all and/or if positions of channels defines the content or names do it.